# count occurrences in unique group combination

Tags: r, unique, combinations

I have a data set that resembles the below:

```
SSN Auto    MtgHe   Personal    Other   None
A   1           1    0          0       0
B   1           1    0          0       0
C   1           0    0          0       0
D   1           0    1          1       0
E   0           0    0          0       1
F   0           0    0          0       1
G   0           0    0          0       1
```

SSN is the person, Auto, MtgHe, Personal, Other are loan categories and 'None' means no loans present.  There are 15 total unique possible loan combinations plus 1 other possibility of 'None' which represents no loans present.  So a person could have only an Auto loan, or an Auto and Personal loan, or no loan at all for example. I would like a count of SSNs that have each different combination. Using the table above the results would look like:

```
Cnt Auto    MtgHe   Personal    Other   None
2   1           1    0          0       0
1   1           0    0          0       0
1   1           0    1          1       0
3   0           0    0          0       1
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this in R?  My data set really has tens of thousands of cases, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, using dplyr's `count` function:

```
library(dplyr)
count(df, Auto, MtgHe, Personal, Other, None) %>% ungroup()
#Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
#
#  Auto MtgHe Personal Other None n
#1    0     0        0     0    1 3
#2    1     0        0     0    0 1
#3    1     0        1     1    0 1
#4    1     1        0     0    0 2
```

And for those who prefer base R and without ordering:

```
x <- interaction(df[-1])
df <- transform(df, n = ave(seq_along(x), x, FUN = length))[!duplicated(x),-1]
#  Auto MtgHe Personal Other None n
#1    1     1        0     0    0 2
#3    1     0        0     0    0 1
#4    1     0        1     1    0 1
#5    0     0        0     0    1 3
```

Comment: So, this dplyr function will calculate all unique combinations in the data set and then add the count?

Comment: Yep it groups the data by all the variables you specify in the `count` (after the `df` which is the data set). It then counts the number of rows for each group and condenses the data to 1 row per group and adds the count column "n".

Comment: `dplyr` isn't the function, it's the package. Normally you'd just load `library(dplyr)` then run the `count(...)` function.

Comment: WOWW! That was easy! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

And the obligatory `data.table` version (the only one that *won't* reorder the data set)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Cnt = .N), .(Auto, MtgHe, Personal, Other, None)]
#    Auto MtgHe Personal Other None Cnt
# 1:    1     1        0     0    0   2
# 2:    1     0        0     0    0   1
# 3:    1     0        1     1    0   1
# 4:    0     0        0     0    1   3
```

Or a shorter version could be

```
temp <- names(df)[-1]
setDT(df)[, .N, temp]
#    Auto MtgHe Personal Other None N
# 1:    1     1        0     0    0 2
# 2:    1     0        0     0    0 1
# 3:    1     0        1     1    0 1
# 4:    0     0        0     0    1 3
```

And just for fun, here's another (unordered) base R version

```
Cnt <- rev(tapply(df[,1], do.call(paste, df[-1]), length))
cbind(unique(df[-1]), Cnt)
#   Auto MtgHe Personal Other None Cnt
# 1    1     1        0     0    0   2
# 3    1     0        0     0    0   1
# 4    1     0        1     1    0   1
# 5    0     0        0     0    1   3
```

And an additional `dplyr` version for completness

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, Auto, MtgHe, Personal, Other, None) %>% tally
# Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
# Groups: Auto, MtgHe, Personal, Other
# 
#   Auto MtgHe Personal Other None n
# 1    0     0        0     0    1 3
# 2    1     0        0     0    0 1
# 3    1     0        1     1    0 1
# 4    1     1        0     0    0 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R solution using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(count ~ ., data=transform(dat[-1],count=1), FUN=sum )

#  Auto MtgHe Personal Other None count
#1    1     0        0     0    0     1
#2    1     1        0     0    0     2
#3    1     0        1     1    0     1
#4    0     0        0     0    1     3
```